# How to add value to a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I have this simple query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT images.id
FROM `images`
WHERE `images`.`user_id` IN
    (SELECT following_id
     FROM `follows`
     WHERE `follows`.`follower_id` = 5717
       AND `follows`.`accepted` = 1)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000
OFFSET 0
```

I want to append a value to the list of values returned by the subquery. So if the subquery returns:

```
23
59
14
77
```

I want it to be:

```
23
59
14
77
86
```

(note the extra 86 at the bottom).

Comment: `... UNION SELECT 86`, if you want 86 on the end even though it's in the resultset (so you'll have it twice): `UNION ALL SELECT 86`

Comment: why not append 42, the answer to everything?

Comment: @FabianBigler I am talking about the subquery...

Comment: @piotrm yea except join makes it a billion times slower and it not as expressive as subquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want 86 to be added, then just use a UNION ALL on the subquery, this will ensure that 86 is always included in your IN clause subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT spentits.id
FROM `spentits`
WHERE `spentits`.`user_id` IN
    (SELECT following_id
     FROM `follows`
     WHERE `follows`.`follower_id` = 5717
       AND `follows`.`accepted` = 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 86)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000
OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just add it as a 2nd piece of criteria in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT spentits.id
FROM `spentits`
WHERE `spentits`.`user_id` IN
    (SELECT following_id
     FROM `follows`
     WHERE `follows`.`follower_id` = 5717
       AND `follows`.`accepted` = 1)
   OR `spentits`.`user_id` = 86
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000
OFFSET 0
```